# Electric field outside dielectrics

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, dielectric

> Explain this statement: “In a static situation, the electric
>   field at the surface of a conductor can have no component parallel
>   to the surface because this would violate the condition that the
>   charges on the surface are at rest.” Would this same statement be
>   valid for the electric field at the surface of an insulator?

I think it'd be valid, because electric field parallel to the surface might cause surface currents. However, inside an insulator we can't use the fact that field inside is zero; which is key to proving the expression for electrostatic pressure in which we safely assume that field is only normal to the surface of the *conductor*

I'm slightly confused, does this have something to do with polarisation? 
Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the essential reason because you can find a nonzero parallel components of the electric field on the surface, is that you will have a polarization charge. It is given by the divergence of the Polarization field. 
In a conductor, the field must "touch" its surface perpendicularly, but in an insulator it is no necessary. This is because the molecules of the media will polarize, this is, the positive and negative charges will "separate" without breaking the molecule. 
There is no reason to restrict the shape of the field at the surface. 
More else, it is a condition that the parallel and normal components of the electric field must be continuous. 
I mean, the more general case for the insulator is in which you have both components, but you can always have the particular case in which the parallel component vanishes.

Comment: If there is indeed a parallel component as you say, won't it lead to surface currents on the insulator? That is something we do not desire as the problem concerns **electrostatics**

Comment: @user28968 Insulators don't have currents just because there's an electric field. That's what makes them different from conductors.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: @user28968 I didn't say that a parallel component is needed, I said that the continuity of the parallel component is needed. That component vanishes without problem. For example if the field is perpendicular to a face of an insulator cube, the only component that you can find at the surface is the normal. As you can see the parallel component vanishes.

Comment: So in general even for insulators there is no parallel component of electric field?

Comment: @user28968 the problem in fact must be specific if there are or no free charge. If there are free charge, there will be a current despite of the fact we are talking about an insulator. But if there are not, it will polarize.

Comment: @user28968 In general, if we talk about insulators there are parallel components. That they can vanishes is different. The no existence of the parallel component: In a conductor is an imposition, in an insulator is a particular case.

Comment: Oh! I see it now. However, I'm still unable to understand one thing. Let's say there's some parallel component of electric field outside an insulator, equal to E in magnitude. If we consider an infinitesimal charge on the surface, say dq, it'll experience a force Edq along the tangent to the insulator at that point: which CONTRADICTS the fact that charges MUST be in equilibrium. Which force counterbalances it, or how do we account for it? Even if it's polarization, a rather detailed argument (mathematical) would be appreciated. Thanks again!

Comment: As I said above, it is related with our conception of an insulator. You must consider the difference of free charge and polarization charge. I sorry but I'm new and I don't know how to put equations here, But If you know the gauss's law we can do it. You have that the divergence of the electric field multiplied by the permeability in the vacuum is equal to a charge density. If you think the charge density as an addition of a polarized charge and a free charge (which is the divergence of the polarization field), you will have the Gauss's law for an insulator.

Comment: The divergence of the electrical displacement field is equal to the free charge. If you have a field component parallel, and free charge on the surface, it will move. But if you don't, you only polarize the material. The difference between a conductor and an insulator is that the free charge (at the rest and in no presence of an electric field) will be at rest in any place of the material (in a conductor it will be on the surface).  This is because the polarization density charge initially are considered zero (of course this not happens if the material was polarized initially).